# The Extended Big-O Definition

Tags: proof-writing, asymptotics

Recall that $g \in \mathcal{O}(f)$ means $$\exists c \in \mathbb{R^+}, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{R^+}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq n_0 \implies g(n) \leq cf(n).$$

I thought of a stronger Big-O definition that we can call big-Zeta, which is $$g \in \zeta(f) : \forall c \in \mathbb{R^+}, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{R^+}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq n_0 \implies g(n) \leq cf(n).$$
What this says instead is that: no matter how much we scale $f$ by, $f$ will eventually dominate $g(n)$. Now, I've thought of an example problem I tried to prove which I believe is true:

For all positive reals $a,b$ with $a < b$ prove that $n^a \in \zeta(n^b)$. Try not to use limits to solve this so the goal is to find an $n_0$.

**Bonus problem*:** Prove that for $f,g$ that map naturals to positive reals, if $g \in \zeta(f)$ then $f \not \in \mathcal{O}(g)$.

(*) This is harder but a clue is that $f$ and $g$ map to **positive** reals.

Comment: You just defined the little-$o$ notation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations

Comment: Oh, haha. Funny that it's called little-o even though it is stronger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what $g\in \mathcal{o}(f)$ means! Note the lower-case $\mathcal{o}$: this is called the [little-$\mathcal{o}$ notation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Little-ONotation.html).